# Parameter name containing special characters on Helm chart

Tags: charts, openshift, kubernetes-helm

In my Helm chart, I need to set the following Java Spring parameter name:

```
company.sms.security.password@id(name):
  secret:
    name: mypasswd
    key: mysecretkey
```

But when applying the template, I encounter a syntax issue.

```
oc apply -f template.yml

The Deployment "template" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[79].name: Invalid value: "company.sms.security.password@id(name)": a valid environment variable name must consist of alphabetic characters, digits, '_', '-', or '.', and must not start with a digit (e.g. 'my.env-name',  or 'MY_ENV.NAME',  or 'MyEnvName1', regex used for validation is '[-._a-zA-Z][-._a-zA-Z0-9]*')
```

What I would usually do is defining this variable at runtime like this:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
-Dcompany.sms.security.password@id(name)=mypass
```

But since it's storing sensitive data, obviously I cannot log in clear the password.
So far I could only think about defining an Initcontainer as a workaround, changing the parameter name is not an option.
Edit: So the goal is to not log the password neither in the manifest nor in the application logs.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

Assign the value from your secret to one environment variable, and use it in the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable value. the way to expand the value of a previously defined variable VAR_NAME, is $(VAR_NAME).

For example:

```yaml
- name: MY_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: mypasswd
      key: mysecretkey
- name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
  value: "-Dcompany.sms.security.password@id(name)=$(MY_PASSWORD)"
```

###### Constrains

There are some conditions for kuberenetes in order to parse the $(VAR_NAME) correctly, otherwise $(VAR_NAME) will be parsed as a regular string:

1. The variable VAR_NAME should be defined *before* the one that uses it
2. The value of VAR_NAME must not be another variable, and must be defined.
   If the value of VAR_NAME consists of other variables or is undefined, $(VAR_NAME) will be parsed as a string.

In the example above, if the secret `mypasswd` **in the pod's namespace** doesn't have a value for the key `mysecretkey`, $(MY_PASSWORD) will appear literally as a string and will not be parsed.

References:

- [Dependent environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/)
- [Use secret data in environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, if I log into the pod and grep for the environment variable I see: company.sms.security.password@id(name)=$(MY_PASSWORD). So the MY_PASSWORD env does not get parsed.

Comment: Another requirement is: I need to loop for different values inside @id(name). So I need a Helm loop for all the names.

Comment: @parax I've edited my answer and added more information to explain the conditions for the parsing of the variable, hope it will help you. About the helm loop, can you provide an example of how the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable should look like in runtime with all the names and passwords in it?

Comment: It seems that helm is always setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in the template before my vars, that's probably why they don't get parsed. However, the solution proposed would not be a fit for my case anyway, since it would log in clear the password in the pods.

Comment: In any case, it might be useful to make it work. So, the process I'm following is: helmfile -f helmfile.yaml -l name=service > template; oc apply -f template. After the helmfile step, the template I have is order alphabetically so I'm not sure how to have the parameter parsed by Helm.